# Possible to find minimum and maximum date associated with unique ID throughout library in SAS?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have many different datasets within a particularly library, and I'm wondering whether there is a way to find a minimum and maximum date associated with a particular unique ID across ALL datasets in a library?

Currently, I can find a local minimum and local maximum date associated with a particular ID within a particular dataset, but this ID will show up again throughout different datasets and have it's own minimum/max date associated with that dataset. But I want to compare the dates on this particular unique ID throughout the entire library, so I can find the global minimum and global maximum date but I do not know how to do this search throughout the entire library.

Currently my code looks like the following

```
DATA SUBSET_MIN_MAX (keep= MIN_DATE MAX_DATE UNIQUEID);
                                    DO UNTIL (LAST.UNIQUEID);
                                    set LIBRARY.&SAS_FILE_N;
                                    BY UNIQUEID;
                                        MIN_DATE = MIN(MIN_DATE,DATE);
                                        MAX_DATE = MAX(MAX_DATE,DATE);
                                    if last.UNIQUEID then output;
                                    END;
                                format MIN_DATE MAX_DATE date9.;
                                RUN;
```

Thanks so much for any assistance.

Comment: I don't think so, because BY will not be honoured correctly across each data set. You can do a PROC MEANS though, which should be faster than a data step on each data set and then combine the results and redo the max/min to see the final results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this using a view and PROC SUMMARY.

```
data d1; set sashelp.class; date=height+ranuni(4); run;
data d2; set sashelp.class; date=height-rannor(5); run;
data d3; set sashelp.class; date=height-ranuni(3); run;
data alld/view=alld;
   length indsname $64;
   set work.d:(keep=name date) indsname=indsname;
   source=indsname;
   run;
proc summary data=alld nway missing;
   class name;
   var date;
   output out=want(drop=_type_) 
      idgroup(max(date) out(source date)=source1 globalmax)
      idgroup(min(date) out(source date)=source2 globalmin)
      ;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]